# password correct but cannot log into Win 7

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I have been using Windows 7 for years and just recently my user password to sign into the computer is acting up.

Here is what happens:
I put in the correct password (been the same thing for a while), and it denies it.
I try it about 10 times and around the 11th try it finally signs in.

Very strange behavior.  I removed the password and tried putting the same again and signed in at another time and it worked, but then today it was acting up again. After many tries (didn't count) it finally signed in.

So what is going on.  I don't have caps lock or num lock enable.  I have been doing the same thing for years and now it starts being weird.

I would like to resolve this annoyance.

Comment: Have you noticed any other issues with typing words anywhere?  Something that might indicate a problem with your physical keyboard like a stuck/broken key?

Comment: Could it be an unreliable keyboard? If you have the option, try hooking up a second one and once you encounter the issue again, try it using the other one and see if that helps. If the circumstances allow, you can also abuse the username field as a testing ground for your typing.

Comment: I use the keyboard on two difference PCs and I type a lot so I doubt it is bad.

Comment: @klandshome Try typing in the password using the virtual keyboard - that would quite definitely rule out any keyboard issues.
Also, try creating another user and working with it - it might be some fault that sticks to that particular account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is becoming corrupt, the most common causes are hard disk dying or windows having a virus or corrupt file, the best fix is a clean install, if you get locked out and cant get in, you can use live linux cd go to windows/system/ rename utilman.exe to utilman2.exe copy cmd.exe and rename it utilman.exe and reboot into windows, then click on ease of access it will open command prompt type net user (username) newpasswod

Comment: Some distros (for example: parted magic) have a tool called "chntpwd" on board. It can be found in the boot menu's "extra" section i think. You can reset a local accounts password to "nothing" relatively fast.

Comment: Three has to be a way without doing a reinstall.  I have an ssd and the pc runs flawlessly.  I doubt there is a virus.  I am an IT guy and and very aware of such things.  Also the disk is fine.  Just that annoying password issue.  Keyboard works well too.

Comment: TO fix it without reinstall you will have to discover the file that is corrupt this is very hard, you need to know programming so you can debug it, rootkit are not easy to find, i have cleaned machine for IT expert who have been infected, you need to use about 5 or 6 tools to be sure

Comment: isn't the corrupt file the password file?

Comment: It is the most likely file to be corrupt as it holds the passwords, but ill try explain, say file1 updates passwordfile and file1 is corrupt when it updates the password file it will always be corrupt since the file to update is corrupt, so it might be another file that changing it.

Comment: @klandshome - Run chkdisk verify there are no problems that are detected.

Comment: Make sure to run it for bad sectors to to be sure there no problem, stage 4 is file integrity check which might be crucial here

Comment: No errors. Even with stage 4.  I have been restarting on and off several times today and no problems so far with the same pass.  Very Strange though.

Comment: I see how a corrupt file would cause this. It would have created a wrong but otherwise stable result every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your Keyboard and the Language. Same thing happened to me but the problem with my computer was some buttons on the keyboard was not working.

You may also try using an external Keyboard.

Hope this helps.